# I want to make a program in C++ on two platforms, Mac and Linux, using GitHub and (a) IDE(s)

Tags: c++, github, ide, repository, cross-platform

Basically I want to use GitHub as my repository and develop on Mac and Linux operating systems. Is this even possible? For example, can I use Xcode on my Mac and Code::Blocks on my Linux OS? Or does it have to be the same IDE, if so any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. In the future though, it would be nice if the question title actually described the question. "I want to make a program in C++...." is not a question. ;)

Comment: Noted, thanks. Please excuse me as I'm new to using this site.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the same standard IDE on each machine to prevent from version conflicts, and compiler variation issues.

It is entirely possible to use two different IDE's but it would be much simpler with one as you would not have to worry about project specific settings in one ide, not being read by the other ide.

If you use "for example" Code::Blocks for each machine, you could just put the entire project to the repository, and git it on another machine, and go right into it and start using it. "providing the ide versions are the same".

For simplicity, I would use one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it’s possible. Take care to ensure:

- Cross-platform code checked in for one platform is compatible with the other
- Platform-specific code does not affect the other platform
- The Xcode and Code::Blocks configurations don’t fall out of sync

It helps immensely to work on a branch, and only merge into `master` once you have tested on all platforms that you wish to support. You can use GitHub’s pull request feature to keep track of feature branches.

The compiler shipped with Xcode is Clang; Code::Blocks uses GCC by default. On one hand, this is good because you’re continually maintaining compatibility with multiple compilers. On the other, it might generate unexpected headaches, as it’s yet another platform difference to manage.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to these answers, you can also setup and use something like [Cmake](http://www.cmake.org) to have a build system that can then be compiled to different IDE's project files on each machine or platform you support. This way, only the cmake files (not Xcode or Code::Blocks projects) are stored in the repository, and setting it up only requires downloading the repository and running Cmake to build the Xcode or Code::Blocks projects from that.

Assuming your code is sufficiently cross platform, this would also make porting to another IDE or OS without much difficulty.

I've used it for several projects, and while I admit that getting things set up takes a bit more time, once its running, only a single set of files needs to be updated when new files, assemblies, and settings are specified.